# Continuous map with increasing coordinates between set and it's thickening.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuous-geometry

Suppose I am working on a compact subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^N$, and I have a closed subset, $A\subset S$. Let $A+\epsilon$ denote the $\epsilon$-thickening of $A$ in $S$ given by:

$$A+\epsilon = \{s \in S: d(s,A)\leq \epsilon\}$$

And let $A-\epsilon$ denote the $\epsilon$-thinning of $A$ in $S$ given by:

$$A-\epsilon = A\setminus\text{Int}(A^c+\epsilon)$$

Here $d$ is the Euclidean distance and Int is the interior. Assume $\epsilon > 0 $ and $A+\epsilon$ and $A-\epsilon$ are non-empty.

I want to find a function $f:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ such that $f$ is strictly increasing in each coordinate (i.e. $z>y \implies f(x_1,...,z,...x_N) > f(x_1,..,.y,...x_N)$ and continuous, such that $f(A)=A+\epsilon$. Is this always possible? What if I substitute $A+\epsilon$ for $A-\epsilon$? How can I show this holds?

---

So far I think I need something like this: Let $a \in A-\epsilon$ and define $f$ as:

$$f(x)=x+\epsilon \frac{x-a}{\|x-a\|}$$

But I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible for $A - \epsilon$, take $A$ to be the unit disk and $\epsilon = 1$. Or something like a filled figure eight so that $A - \epsilon$ is disconnected. For $A + \epsilon$ I expect you need some sort of convexity for $A$, if $A$ has smooth boundary then you don't want the coordinates of the outward normal to change signs too frequently (compared to $\epsilon$). Assuming some such condition, you can probably cook up something by flowing along the outward normal.